# Unable to add xamarin.forms.map control to Xamarin Form

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dex, xamarin.forms.maps

I want to add a map control to my android app.
To do this I have got the latest xamarin.forms and xamarin.forms.maps packages from Nuget.

My code behind logic does nothing at all, and my axml page looks like as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/optionsContainerLinearLayout">
           //Other UI elements
        <maps:Map>
        </maps:Map>
        </LinearLayout>
...
</LinearLayout>
```

Note I've but no tags within maps:Map so as to provide minimal chance for errors. Note that when I populate this map with more properties as directly below, the code still breaks in the same way:

```
<map:Map
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mockMapView">
</map:Map>
```

When I run this application, it breaks on `SetContentView()` with the error:

```
Didn't find class "android.view.Map" on path: DexPathList
[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.geosolve.pavestate2-fJtHBLcT2gY6AlUrxcOOVg==/base.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.geosolve.pavestate2-fJtHBLcT2gY6AlUrxcOOVg==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.geosolve.pavestate2-fJtHBLcT2gY6AlUrxcOOVg==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
```

I've got another sample xamarin application I downloaded which runs fine on my emulator, so I don't think the emulator is the problem.
I have my API key being used by this other application as well, so I don't think the API key is the problem either.

My androidManifest.xml looks like so:

```
...
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/icon" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/GeosolveApp">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="(My API Key)" />
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
...
```

[image: Exception]

Any help as to why this isn;'t just showing up like you would expect?

Comment: you appear to be confusing Xamarin Forms and Xamarin Android.  LinearLayout is an Android layout, not a Forms layout.  If you want to add maps to a Xamarin Android app, see here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/

Comment: @Jason I'm not sure I understand your distinction... All of the tutorials I have looked at on adding maps to android use the xamarin.forms.maps package, which in turn relies on the xamarin.forms package. So it seems to me that Android projects can use xamarin forms.... or am I missing something here?

Comment: I pointed you to the official docs - I can't comment on what you might be following because I haven't read it

Comment: Hey @Jason, after reading through the docs, I found that I would do better to use <fragments> rather than <map> elements. If you want to post some kind of answer pointing out that my axml layout didn't correspond with the syntax in the docs, then I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Xamarin.Android,we usually [install the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps package from NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/maps-api#install-gpsmaps-nuget).

And add the map in your xaml like:

**Declaratively** :

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/map"
   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

**Programmatically** :

```
var mapFrag = MapFragment.NewInstance();
activity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                        .Add(Resource.Id.map_container, mapFrag, "map_fragment")
                        .Commit();
```

the more you could read [Google Maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/maps-api#install-gpsmaps-nuget).